# How to correctly minimize this loss funcion w.r.t. the matrix elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am trying to find the linear transformation that transforms a set of $J$ lines as close as possible to another set of $N$ lines, both defined as vectors $l=(a,b,c)$ such that $l \cdot x = 0$.

The way I formulated this is a sort of OLS solution, i.e. minimizing the loss function

$$
\mathcal{L} = \sum_i^N \sum_j^J (\vec{y}^{(i)}-A\vec{x}^{(j)})^2
$$

where $\vec{x}^{(j)}$ are predefined (known) vectors, that undergo a transformation $A$, and I want this transformation to be such that the average distance between the resulting vectors $A\vec{x}^{(j)}$ and another set of vectors $\vec{y}^{(i)}$ is minimized.

I tried to calculate this by computing the partial derivatives w.r.t. the elements, and setting the gradient to zero, this way I get a liner system of 9 equations:

$$
A_{k,1} \left( \sum_{i}^N \sum_j x_l^{(j)}x_1^{(j)} \right) + A_{k,2} \left( \sum_{i}^N \sum_j x_l^{(j)}x_2^{(j)} \right) + A_{k,3} \left( \sum_{i}^N \sum_j x_l^{(j)}x_3^{(j)} \right) = \sum_i^N \sum_j x_l^{(j)}y_k^{(i)}
$$

but I'm not sure this solution is correct, in facts every time I compute it I get different indices lol.

Is there a better way to do this or just a correct solution to my problem?

Comment: Can you define correctly $x^{(i)}$ and $y^{(j)}$

Comment: @Youem yes! Sorry I edited the post to maybe clarify it a bit. Both the set of vectors $x^{(j)}$ and $y^{(i)}$ are known. I want to find the matrix $A$ such that, when applied to the vectors $x$, the average distance between the resulting vectors and the set of $y$ is minimized. The context is computer vision, and $A$ is actually the transpose inverse of a homography matrix.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathcal{L} = \sum_i^N \sum_j^J ‖\vec{y}^{(i)}-A\vec{x}^{(j)}‖^2$ instead of $\mathcal{L} = \sum_i^N \sum_j^J (\vec{y}^{(i)}-A\vec{x}^{(j)})^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be rephrased as a standard least squares problem, and we can even generalize it a bit. First, collect the vectors in matrices:

- $X≔[x^{(1)}, …, x^{(J)}]^⊤∈ℝ^{J×K}$  (assuming $x^{(j)}∈ℝ^K$)
- $Y≔[y^{(1)}, …, y^{(N)}]^⊤∈ℝ^{N×D}$  (assuming $y^{(n)}∈ℝ^D$)
- $≔ X⊗_N = (x^{(j)}_k)_{jn,k}∈ℝ^{J×N×K}$   ($N$ copies)
- $≔ _J ⊗ Y = (y^{(n)}_d)_{jn,d}∈ℝ^{J×N×D}$   ($J$ copies)

Then the problem can be rewritten as:

$$ ℒ(A) = ∑_{n=1}^N∑_{j=1}^J‖y^{(n)}-Ax^{(j)}‖^2 = ‖ - ⋅A‖^2$$

Where $⋅A$ is the tensor contraction $⋅A ≔ (∑_k _{jnk}A_{kd})_{jnd}$ and $‖⋅‖^2$ is the induced norm on $ℝ^{J×N×D}$. Taking gradient with respect to $A$ yields the good old normal equation:

$$ ∇_Aℒ(A) = -2^⊤⋅( - ⋅A) \overset{!}{=} 0 ⟺ ^⊤  A = ^⊤ $$

Here, $^⊤ $ is the tensor contraction $(∑_{jn} _{jn,k'}_{jn,k})_{k',k}$ and $^⊤ = (∑_{jn}_{jn,k}_{jn,d})_{k,d}$, so, if $^⊤ $ is invertible then $A = (^⊤ )^{-1}^⊤$.

To implement, the best option is likely to simply flatten the $J$ and $N$ axes and use a builtin least-squares method, e.g. in numpy:

```
import numpy as np

N, J, K, D = 100, 10, 5, 3

x = np.random.randn(J, K)
y = np.random.randn(N, D)

# construct X, Y
X = np.einsum("jk, n -> jnk", x, np.ones(N))
Y = np.einsum("j, nd -> jnd", np.ones(J), y)

# flatten
X = X.reshape(J*N, K)
Y = Y.reshape(J*N, D)

# solve least squares
A = np.linalg.lstsq(X, Y, rcond=None)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the kind of algebraic approach I was missing. I think the problem is a bit ill-posed though, because the matrix I get when using this approach has determinant that's almost zero (i.e. all the $X$ vectors  get squashed into a single point). Do you think that there might be an issue with how the problem is formulated? Maybe we could add some sort of regularization in a nice analytical way that eliminates such solutions?

Comment: @AlessandroZanoli The normal equation is always solvable, even if $^⊤$ is singular, in which case infinitely many solutions exist. The "preferred" solution in this case is $A^* ≔ ^+$, given by the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) (note: we need to flatten again), which is the unique minimal norm solution. (i.e. $A^* = \arg\min\{‖A‖² ∣ ^⊤ A = ^⊤\}$.

Comment: @AlessandroZanoli The standard regularization is called Tikhonov/L²-regularization, also called [Ridge Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_regression). It simply consists of adding a term of the form $λ‖A‖²$. The pseudoinverse solution is the limiting solution for $λ→0$.

Comment: @AlessandroZanoli In this case the normal equation simply becomes $(^⊤+λ)A = ^⊤$, and you see that the matrix on the LHS is guaranteed to be full rank. In fact, the larger $λ$, the better the condition number.

Comment: So the regularization helps but I am not sure that it helps in identifying the correct solution; I should specify that the minimizing matrix $A$  I'm seeking is actually the inverse transpose of a [homography matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography), that actually has 8 free parameters (in $D=3$), but I think this translates to non linear constraint in the matrix $A$. I am minimizing the inverse transpose because it is my understanding that, when a line $l$ is defined as $\vec{l}\cdot \vec{x}$, it is mapped according to $\vec{l}' = H^{-T}\vec{l}$

Comment: Nevermind I think I found a simple solution. Just invert the $X$ and $Y$ sets and minimize on $H^T$ directly with the linear constraint that $H^T_{3,3}=1$.